# use regex matches as markers for text extraction

Tags: python, regex, search, extract

**My code so far**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os, sys, re, codecs
```

## Part 1

```
f = open("Krupp.txt", "r")
contents = f.read()

f.close() #close the file

date_pattern = "(Montag|Dienstag|Mittwoch|Donnerstag|Freitag|Samstag|Sonnabend|Sonntag)(, )
([123][0-9]|[1-9])(. )
(Januar|Februar|März|April|Mai|Juni|Juli|August|September|Oktober|November|Dezember)
( )([0-2][0-9][0-9][0-9])"

# finds all dates, prints them below eachother and writes them to file 
(writing is for test purposes)
with open("testoutput.txt", "a+") as f:
    for m in re.finditer(date_pattern, contents):
        print m.group(0)
        f.write(m.group(0))
        f.write("\n")
```

## Part 2

```
# extracts text between target1 and target2
target1 = 'date_1'
target2 = 'date_2'
elements = '{}(.+?){}'.format(target1,target2)
pattern = re.compile(elements, flags=re.DOTALL)
results = pattern.findall(contents)
```

**The file I'd like to search**

```
Mittwoch, 15. März 2017
14:30 Uhr
17:30 Uhr
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, 
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, 
sed diam voluptua.
Donnerstag, 16. März 2017
Samstag, 18. März 2017
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, 
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, 
sed diam voluptua.
Greifswald, 16 - 18 March 2017
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, 
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, 
Donnerstag, 16. März 2017
17:30 Uhr
19:00 Uhr
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, 
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, 
sed diam voluptua.
```

**My Output**

```
Mittwoch, 15. März 2017

Donnerstag, 16. März 2017

Samstag, 18. März 2017

Donnerstag, 16. März 2017
```

**What I want**

As you can see the code extracts the dates written in a specific german format. And the second part searches between two strings.
I need a way to use the dates found from Part 1 as target1 and target2 in Part 2. 
This way I would like to extract these parts:

```
Mittwoch, 15. März 2017
14:30 Uhr
17:30 Uhr
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, 
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, 
sed diam voluptua.
```

And later write those parts into single files.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: I do not see, how this could be a duplicate

Comment: Perhaps not, as I saw your `elements = '{}(.+?){}'.format(target1,target2)`. So help me understand, what difficulty are you having? Are you needing help extracting the dates from the full regex in part 1?

Comment: You could use an expression like `(Montag|Dienstag|Mittwoch|Donnerstag|Freitag|Samstag|Sonnabend|Sonntag).+?(?=Montag|Dienstag|Mittwoch|Donnerstag|Freitag|Samstag|Sonnabend|Sonntag)` with dotall to find chunks of desired text and _then_ parse the chunks for what you want. Note this pattern will not find the final text chunk.